# Figuring out the dynamic fields in ruby mvc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't know ruby but trying to figure out how `user` id is getting populated after loging into a website. In the ruby code,I see that MVC for Ruby has been used by someone and I am currently inside  the "views" folder, Inside layout folder there is a file called "application.html".

I am referring to the following piece of code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            <% if admin2? %>
            var userrole = 'admin';
            var isAdmin = true;
            <% elsif registrar? %>
            var userrole = 'registrar';
            var isAdmin = false;
            <% elsif viewer? %>
            var userrole = 'viewer';
            var isAdmin = false;
            <% end %>
            var myuserID = <%= user? %>;
```

When I log into the website, and do "View Page Source", I see all the variables values. I am trying to figure out how `var myuserID = 12` value is getting populated. Does this looks like session variables in ruby? Could anyone give some sort of hint to where I should be looking for so that I can figure out how the dynamic fields are getting populated?

I can see a `session.rb` defined in the `models` folder and it has only few lines as follows :

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :user_id


end
```

Could the above be responsible for getting the user_id?

Comment: There are erb tags which load data from ruby. Search the app code for admin2 to find where it's defined

Comment: @maxpleaner In one of the erb I did find something like this `{"result":<%= @result.to_json %>, "user_id":<%= @user.id.to_json %>}

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using Rails given the presence of ActiveRecord. Anytime there are local variables referenced in the view layer of a Rails application, those variables must either be defined within that view or are provided using a helper.

Check the project's `helpers` directory and see if there are any methods providing the types of local variables you find in the view.

If you still don't find any helpers, you can also look for any declaration of `helper_method` in a controller after a definition of the view's local variable name.

Other helper methods can be provided by imported libraries. To investigate that further you'll need to look in the Gemfile and see what gems are being included and read their documentation to find out what methods they expose to the view layer.

Comment: Helpers are there inside a separate helper folder but I couldn't find the specific variable inside `users_helpers.rb`. One of the method which looks promising to me is defined as follows :

`def link_to_current_user(options={})
    if current_user
      link_to_user current_user, options
    else
      content_text = options.delete(:content_text) || 'not signed in'
      # kill ignored options from link_to_user
      [:content_method, :title_method].each{|opt| options.delete(opt)} 
      link_to_login_with_IP content_text, options
    end
  end`

Comment: `current_user` is a common paradigm for handling user authentication, I suspect you're receiving the helper methods from a gem that's being used. Check your Gemfile and see which gems are being included that have to do with Users and read that gem's documentation. You'll probably find what you're looking for.